# How to parse JSON string to struct

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have `struct` of Request, value is optional:

```
type Request struct {
    Operation string      `json:"operation"`
    Key string            `json:"key"`
    Value string          `json:"value"`
}
```

And function that should parse json string to struct^

```
go func() {
    s := string("{'operation': 'get', 'key': 'example'}")
    data := Request{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data)
    log.Printf("Operation: %s", data.Operation)
}
```

For some reason data.Operation is empty. What is wrong here?

Comment: You also have a `go` keyword with without a function call. If that's a typo missing the `()`, you then have a goroutine without any synchronization.

Comment: As is one of the most common issues out there, _don't ignore errors_.  json.Unmarshal returns an error type.  The output of that error would have told you that your json had invalid quotes, and after you fixed that, would have told you that your destination variable needed to be a pointer.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Two problems, first, your json is invalid, it needs to use `"` instead of `'`

Second, you have to unmarshal into `&data` and not to `data`

https://play.golang.org/p/zdMq5_ex8G

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Request struct {
    Operation string      `json:"operation"`
    Key string            `json:"key"`
    Value string          `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    s := string(`{"operation": "get", "key": "example"}`)
    data := Request{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data)
    fmt.Printf("Operation: %s", data.Operation)
}
```

Side note, you would have seen this, if you would have been checking your errors:

```
s := string("{'operation': 'get', 'key': 'example'}")

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error()) 
    //json: Unmarshal(non-pointer main.Request)
}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error()) 
    //invalid character '\'' looking for beginning of object key string
}
```